# jqgrid/ how to create selectbox dynamically loading select options

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I want to create a selectbox which loads select options dynamically using json data.

The 'cooperation id' is a selectbox and all i want to do is getting data from other database table so i put the url in the 'dataURL' and use the 'buildselect' to get json data.
I've got no options in selectbox when i tested. I think i miss something or something is wrong in my code.

here is my code below.

```
jQuery(function($) {

            jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
                url: '/jqGrid/merchantEstablishmentList',
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 'auto', autowidth: true,
                colNames:
                [   
                    'Establishment ID',
                    'Establish Name',
                    'Corporation ID'
                ],
        colModel:
                [
                    {name:'ESTABLISHMENT_ID',index:'ESTABLISHMENT_ID',  editable:true, sortable:false,search: false},
                    {name:'ESTABLISHMENT_NAME',index:'ESTABLISHMENT_NAME', editable:true, sortable:false,search: false},
                    {name:'CORPORATE_ID',index:'CORPORATE_ID', sortable:false,edittype:"select", editable:true, search: false, editoptions: {
                        dataUrl : '/jqGrid/getMerchantsID/?m_type=corp.html?type=json'
                        ,buildSelect:function (data) {
                            value = jQuery.parseJSON(data).combo;
                            var result = '<select>';
                            for(var idx=0; idx < value.length; idx++) {
                                result += '<option value="' + value[idx] + '">' + value[idx] + '</option>';
                            }
                            result += '</select>';
                            return result;
                        }
                    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If would be good if you append the text of your question with the response from `/jqGrid/getMerchantsID/?m_type=corp.html?type=json`.

Which version of jqGrid you use? If you use *the current version of jqGrid* and if your server returns correct formatted data then you should use `data.combo` instead of `jQuery.parseJSON(data).combo`. Additionally you should add `var` before `value`. Your current code of `buildSelect` declare implicitly **global** `value` variable.