# jquery & ajax _ call data from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I'm trying to create a dynamic select box which is using jqgrid-plugin.
I want to call data from my database(oracle) and put it in the select box so that the called data would be showed within select box. I'm not an expert at jquery and ajax. 
I've tried to edit the 'edittype' and 'edditoptions' which are attributes of jqgrid colModel[] but it wasn't proper situation.

How can i call data from database to use ajax.

Here is my code below related to jgGrid columns.

```
jQuery(function($) {

                    jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid({
                        url: '/jqGrid/merchantEstablishmentList',
                        datatype: 'json',
                        height: 'auto', autowidth: true,
                        colNames:
                                [
                                    'Establishment ID',
                    'Establish Name',
                    'Corporation ID'
                ],
                colModel:
                [
                    {name:'ESTABLISHMENT_ID',index:'ESTABLISHMENT_ID',  editable:true, sortable:false,search: false},
                    {name:'ESTABLISHMENT_NAME',index:'ESTABLISHMENT_NAME', editable:true, sortable:false,search: false},
                    {name:'CORPORATE_ID',index:'CORPORATE_ID',editable:true,edittype:"select", editoptions:{value : },editrules:{required:true},sortable:false,search: false},

                ],
```

Comment: what about [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26828245/315935) which uses `dataUrl` and `buildSelect`. It's correct way. You can use Developer Tools of IE or Chrome (press F12 to start) to see HTTP traffic and to test whether `dataUrl: '/jqGrid/getMerchantsID/?m_type=corp.html?type=json'` returns any data.

Comment: @Oleg i've tried but my select box show only 'undefined'...

Comment: I wrote you in my answer that you should include the server response in your answer. You should use Developer Tools, [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and examine HTTP traffic. You will see the exact response from `dataUrl`. After that one can fix the code of `buildSelect`.